# Does Recursive call works as goto?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a method that i have to call it from itself for multiple times in order to get a result and i want to know is `Recursive` call work as `goto` in this situation ?

Dummy Code:

```
public int DummyMethod()
{
    string token;
    int result = -1;

    token = GetNewToken();

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (result == -1)
    {
        if (stopwatch.Elapsed >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(350)) { 
            //This is related to some logic as the token for the website 
            //expires after 350 seconds.
            result = DummyMethod();
            continue; //DO I NEED TO USE contunue ? or the recursive 
                      //call broke the method (as if i used goto)
        }

        result = GetResultFromWebSite(token);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a step-by-step of what your method is supposed to do?

Comment: @gunr2171 the method connects to a site getting a new connection token then tries to pull some data that are not necessarily available all the time so the timeout may exceed the 350 seconds and the token expires so i need to re do everything from the beginning in order to get a new token and wait for the data again... and finally return the data when available.

Comment: What you are doing really doesn't make a lot of sense. If the token has expired, then *presumably* `GetResultFromWebSite` will give you some kind of error and you'll use that to determine that you should get a new token and try again. You certainly shouldn't be trying to determine if the token has expired yourself. What happens when the website changes their expiration time?

Comment: @DanielEugen It seems that you do not need recursion in this case.

Comment: @MattBurland it is site behavior i can't control because it is not my site... when the 350 seconds pass they simple don't return any thing...

Comment: @DanielEugen: Then you should have a TimeoutException in there somewhere. You don't show the code from `GetResultFromWebSite`, but you need to give it a resonable amount of time and if it doesn't respond, either retry (possibly after a delay) or throw an exception.

Comment: @DanielEugen Just usual iteration looks OK for this case. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead use

```
return DummyMethod();
```

which is a tail call (the compiler can turn it into a goto).

This is a good illustration of one way the "single entry/single return" mantra fails.

However, I'm pretty sure you could just build this into the loop and avoid recursion:

```
public int DummyMethod()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string token = GetNewToken();
    int result;
    do
    {
        if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 350) {
            token = GetNewToken();
            stopwatch.Restart();
        }

        result = GetResultFromWebSite(token);
    } while (result == -1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but it sound to me that no recursion is needed at all. It looks rather as a typical busy loop.

Comment: @AlexD: You're correct that no recursion is needed.  There is some logic required to get the token reissued every 350 seconds however, if I'm understanding the question correctly.  Your answer builds a new token far too often.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this all wrong and you definitely shouldn't be trying to figure out if your token has expired. This should be something the server tells you. If it comes via an exception you could do something like this:

```
public int DummyMethod(int retries = 0)
{
    string token;
    try 
    {
        token = GetNewToken();
        return GetResultFromWebSite(token);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (retries < 4) // or whatever max you want - you probably shouldn't hardcode it
        {
            return DummyMethod(++retries);
        }
        throw new Exception("Server ain't responding");
    }
}
```

In a situation like this, it's often a good idea to have a maximum number of retries after which you will give up and show an error message.

Comment: can we speak private a for a sec i can show you the code and the real scenario ?

Comment: @DanielEugen: This is a QA site not a private chat site. Talking in private might help you put doesn't help anybody else reading this question. You ought to be able to sketch out the basics of how this works without giving away anything proprietary.

Comment: i will come back and edit the question to suite the answer we got to so everybody benefits... it is just something i could't understand yet so thought you might give a little bit of help :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to know how to stop the recursion. This is normally done with a condition where the result is clear and returned without calling the recursive function again. This way the endless calling of the recursive method is stopped and the recursion will come to an end. You dont use a goto for that like you simply never should use goto ;)

Comment: @DanielEugen [This](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

Comment: @DanielEugen Two main reasons.  The first is that it breaks the normal flow of control of the program which can lead to weird bugs, and the second is that it can quickly become very difficult to read a program using goto, especially if you are using goto between different source files.

Answer (score 0):

No, recursive calls are not equivalent to goto statements.

You don't even need to use recursion to solve your problem.  If you place your call to `GetNewToken` in the loop, you can check the result and use `continue` to perform another iteration if you don't get the desired results.  If you do get the desired result, you can call `GetResultFromWebSite` and return its result immediately.